# Extension of PHP `round()` for PHP_ROUND_UP and PHP_ROUND_DOWN

Tags: php, performance, floating-point

While looking at PHP.net this afternoon, I saw a comment in `round()` for two functions for rounding `UP` and `DOWN` (as opposed to just `HALF_UP` and `DOWN`).  I liked the suggestion, but wanted a solution that was one function instead of 3, so I came up with the following:

```
define('PHP_ROUND_UP',   11);
define('PHP_ROUND_DOWN', 12);

function fround($number, $precision = 0, $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) {
    if(is_string($number)) {
        $number = preg_replace('/,/','',$number);
    }
    if (is_numeric($number) && !empty($number)) {
        switch($mode) {
            case PHP_ROUND_UP:
            case PHP_ROUND_DOWN:
                $invert = (bool) ($number < 0);
                if($invert) {
                    $number *= -1;
                }
                if (!empty($precision)) {
                    $precision = pow(10, (int) $precision);
                    $number *= $precision;
                }
                if ($mode == PHP_ROUND_UP) {
                    $number = ceil($number);
                } else {
                    $number = floor($number);
                }
                if (!empty($precision) && !empty($number)) {
                    $number /= $precision;
                }
                if($invert) {
                    $number *= -1;
                }
                break;
            default:
                $number = round($number, $precision, $mode);
                break;
        }
    }
    return (float) $number;
}
```

My questions are about overhead/performance, and really anything else you may have to say.  For options other than `PHP_ROUND_UP` or `PHP_ROUND_DOWN` it adds minimal overhead, save for stripping commas if the input number is a string (I realize this is additional to what PHP's `round()` does), so I guess I am asking about the internal logic for `PHP_ROUND_UP` and `PHP_ROUND_DOWN`.

The comment that sparked this for me [is here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php#114573).

[REVISION](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115455/revision-extension-of-php-round-for-php-round-up-and-php-round-down)

Comment: Mike, if you have taken advice from the answer given to change your code, then you should post a new question with your new code.  We have a policy about changing the code or the question after reviews have been given. [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: 10-4, I just did a quick browse on Meta to double-check, as posting a new CR for every revision seems like it would add a considerable amount of data to SO, but, indeed, it seems that all Meta questions on the topic are all about un-reviewed code, and the handful about reviewed code are just that: "Post again."  My bad.

Comment: Side-Note: It would be nice if there was a "Post Revision" button, that created a link to the new revision, would help tying them all together, direct the crowd/conversation, etc.  It would also make the requirement clearer.  Maybe I will mention this on Meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General**

Instead of having your function convert string values to numbers, throw an error if, for example `!is_float($number)`. `round()` only accepts a float value, so I think you should follow their convention.

Also, this will allow you to remove `is_numeric()` (or, above, you could check for `is_numeric()` only).

This if-condition doesn't have an else, so when poor input is entered, the user could potentially not get any response at all -- terrible for debugging!

**Performance**

`empty($number)` is checked two times, you can reduce that to none since `is_float()` will automatically return false if there is nothing (or throw an error is there's no argument).

Comment: Yes, the `preg_replace` deviates from `round()`'s convention, and probably should not be included, but I put it in my function because it deals with some numbers from a DB, I may modify to filter outside the function first.  I think `is_numeric()` is appropriate, as `round()` accepts any numeric value.  As for getting "nothing," the function will return an empty `(float)`, which follows convention `0 === round('hello');`  As for `$invert`, this is nessesary to mimic `round()` behaviour with negative numbers `-124 === round(-123.5) && 124 === round(123.5)`.  I will clean up.

Comment: @Mike On second glance, `is_numeric()` is comparable to what's in `round()`, so that's fine. And `$invert` seems appropriate, I hadn't used round() in a while and had to go test it out!

Comment: Updated, the use of `xor` is much more performant, and I LOVE getting a chance to use it when I can.

Comment: Haha very clever, if I think of anything else I'll edit my answer!